In welding, why we use active gas like CO2 when We want protection from oxygen/oxidation?
I taught that, oxidation is the reason we need shielding gas (apart from other physics like arc characteristics), then why we use active gas? Even we use directly oxygen (even small but why, when we hate it in our welding) and CO2 and even hydrogen when hydrogen is a big issue in cracks and CO2 has oxygen?

Since when is CO2 an "active gas". I started editing this post, but it's pretty much unintelligible.

I agree, there is currently not much to salvage. Please try to reiterate your question with shorter, but more sentences.

Mostly it's because carbon dioxide is cheaper and sufficiently inert for welding of pure copper or copper alloys that do not contain too much of more reactive elements; pure copper is significantly oxidized by elemental oxygen but not by carbon dioxide (or by water vapor, a selectivity used in a classic test for air versus moisture leaks in furnaces). Most commonly welded metals other than copper, such as steel, would be oxidized by carbon dioxide. But even with copper-based materials argon, or an argon-helium mixture, is more common. See, for instance, https://www.forsteramerica.com/tips-welding-copper/.
